# How to remove item from Ansible list?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need remove some item from list

```
"my_list_one": [
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3"
] }
```

I need remove item which includes string "2". As result, I need list as

```
"my_list_one": [
    "item1",
    "item3"
] }
```

How could I realize it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? (Ansible is not a programming language, why would you use it for list manipulation)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A nicer variation of @techraf's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41818455/2795592):

```
{{ my_list_one | reject('search','2') | list }}
```

Comment: I don't understand. what is `reject(`? a jinja builtin-filter? and what is 'search'? is that a python function or an ansible thing?

Comment: `reject` is a Jinja filter (native); `search` is Jinja test (implemented by Ansible).

Comment: thanks! i found the doc for reject [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs) but how do i find more jinja tests implemented by ansible? EDIT: found it! thanks again [jinja tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#tests)  and [ansible tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html)

Comment: [Actual reject() docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject)

Comment: If you want a direct comparison, use `'equalto'`. If the value to reject is the output of a calculation you may need to filter it through `| string`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pop()` or `remove()` depending on your needs.

`pop(n)` removes the n-th element for list (starting with 0). Negative n values starts counting from the end of the list.

```
- debug:
    msg: |
      {% set result = [] %}
      {% for i in range(0, 30, 5) %}
      {%   set _ = result.append(i) %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% set _ = result.pop(3) %}
      {{ result }}

-> 0, 5, 10, 20, 25, 30

- debug:
    msg: |
      {% set result = [] %}
      {% for i in range(0, 30, 5) %}
      {%   set _ = result.append(i) %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% set _ = result.pop(-1) %}
      {{ result }}

-> 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
```

`remove(item)` removes the `item` from the list (if exist):

```
- debug:
    msg: |
      {% set result = [] %}
      {% for i in range(0, 30, 5) %}
      {%   set _ = result.append(i) %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% set _ = result.remove(20) %}
      {{ result }}

-> 0, 5, 10, 15, 25, 30
```

Comment: These are based on the positions. The question is about how to search for a keyword and pop it from the list.